# grails - No signature of method: save()

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm using grails 2.1.1 and I getting the message "No signature of method: ClassA.save() is applicable for argument types: () values: []" when trying to save an object in production environment.

This is the code:

```
def method(campId, userId){
    ClassA cbl = new ClassA()
    cbl.userId = userId
    cbl.campId = campId
    cbl.save(flush:true)
}
```

This code works fine in development but when I execute the code in production I have this problem.

Comment: Are you sure, that there is no meta-magic applied to your ClassA save() method somewhere in you app?

Comment: Thanks Anton, I could solve the problem... The classA had not any meta-magic... I changed the domain and table names and now it works. I don't know why...

Comment: That's nice that everything works, but let me ask what did you mean as "and table name"? I hope you didn't create the tables manually? Because grails creates them for you autmatically :)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to look out for

You say it works in dev but not in production so the first starting point of any investigation is what is the difference between both. Meaning do a `show create table class_a` on both product/development environments.

It maybe something has changed and it has some required value that is no longer provided

Step 2:

It is obviously not saving so you need to see if any errors are thrown

```
def method(campId, userId){
    if (campId && userId) {
    try {
    ClassA cbl = new ClassA()
    cbl.userId = userId
    cbl.campId = campId
    if (!cbl.save(flush:true)) {
      //println cbl.errors
      //log.info "${cbl.errors}"
    }
    }catch (Exception e) {
      //println "E really happended $e"
    }
   }else {
     println "oh my ... a certain value has not been provided"
   }
}
```

You see in above code an if statement to ensure both values provided since you are setting without checking, the try catch was last alternative to try but the if it saves println error is the next thing to try

Finally there are many ways to save a class just in case as Anton suggest you have some other inbuild functions in ClassA when it comes to saving and `new ClassA()` may cause an issue maybe since you are missing

```
ClassA() {
  super()
}
```

or something then I would lastly try this as a test

```
  ClassA cbl = new ClassA(userId:userId,campId:campId)?.save(flush:true)
```

Same logic applied differently

Comment: Hi vahid, thanks for your answer, I tried using "show create table" and I did not see differences between both tables. I also tried changing the logic as you said but the problem remains.

Comment: This may give you a clue http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/groovy-goodness-get-hints-about-missing.html. I sugggest you re-write it from scratch top to bottom. Also if there was a problem saving the try catch and println suggested should have given you further errors to give more of a clue if it was save related - starting to think it is something else somewhere else happening maybe as part of save

Comment: Thanks vahid, the problem was that grails was not recognizing the domain (I tried using other grails domain method and didn't ) I change the domain and table names and everything works ok now. I don't know wich the really problem was. (sorry for my english)